# Node.js Seperate each line into an array of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to access a text file and have an array and have each line to be an array of numbers.

It returns on node.js

```
9235
9096 637
```

and I want it to return

```
[[9235],
[[9096],[637]]
```

Index.js

```
console.log("Hello World");
var fs = require('fs');
var array = fs.readFileSync('txt/numbers.txt').toString().split("\n");
for(i in array) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

numbers.txt

```
9235 
9096 637
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other answers aren't correct and you actually wanted an array of arrays for each line:

```
array.map(function(line) {
    return line.match(/\d+/g).map(function (n) {
        return [+n];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the lines, then use `.split(" ")` to get an array of numbers, and push them to an array.

```
console.log("Hello World");
var fs = require('fs');
var lines = fs.readFileSync('numbers.txt', 'utf8').split("\n");

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    //push each line as an array of numbers
    result.push(lines[i].trim().split(" ").map(Number)); 
                                         // ^ convert items to integer
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //[[9235],[9096,637]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it..

```
            var ar = ["9235", "9096 637"];

            for (var i in ar) {
                var e = ar[i];
                if (e.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
                    ar[i] = e.split(" ");
                } else {
                    ar[i] = new Array(e);
                }
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(ar));
```